# JProfiler 8.1 not able to show souce or byte code in Mac 10.10

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, jprofiler

I am using JProfiler 8.1. It's great tool. I have successfully integrated it with Eclipse.
I am doing memory profile able to lunch Heap walker and trying to find source code from Object graph but it's not working.Anything I am missing?or you have pointer to solve this issue?

Comment: It would help to provide more details and context around the error you are observing.

Comment: If you start profiling from eclipse and invoke show the show source action, the JProfiler eclipse will show the source file in the eclipse IDE.